# Is subMap of NavigableMap going to cause memory leak?

Tags: java, dictionary, memory-leaks

In Java, `NavigableMap` has a method `subMap()` which returns a view of the portion of this map whose keys range from `fromKey` to `toKey`. In the documentation, it says that the returned map is backed by this map, so changes in the returned map are reflected in this map, and vice-versa.

So my question is if you assign the `subMap` of a `NavigableMap` to itself, is it going to cause a potential memory leak? I mean part of the original map is not referenced any more.

```
NavigableMap<E> map = map.subMap(fromKey, toKey);
```

Comment: Yes that will cause a memory leak in a sense of the word. The entries outside of the `subMap()` range will remain in memory while there is still a reference to the submap.

Comment: But if you stop referencing the `subMap`, then it'll all get GC'd correctly.  It only becomes a memory leak if you hold onto the `subMap` yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can possibly create a cyclic reference.

But, Java's GC doesn't have a problem with cyclic references. Basically, it scans the whole heap once in a while and removes the ones aren't reachable.